# Every Google app stopped working and I cannot act on this

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, google, huawei, google-play-services

Yesterday morning suddenly all my google apps (except partially Chrome) stopped working at the same time and I don't understand why, and surprisingly enough I cannot even act on this via the usual Google settings.

More precisely, this is a list of the issues:

1. Whatever thing I try to search in Google Search, YouTube, Google Maps and Google Play, they get stuck and let me wait forever without showing any result, and I have to terminate them.
2. Nothing happens if I uninstall the updates for these apps, leaving the preinstalled versions.
3. If I click on "Manage space" when selecting "Google Play Services", the corresponding window appears but disappears immediately after less than one second, thus preventing me from clearing data (for example).
4. If I select my Google account in "Accounts" and I click on "delete account" the account is never deleted and stays there, without generating any error message.
5. All the apps relying on Google services (like the apps which use Google Maps) are not working properly, some of them get even closed suddenly without generating any error message (perhaps because they get unexpected behaviour from the Google services.

So my two questions are:

1. Why is this happening? Do you have any clue?
2. How can I make my Google apps and services work again? I have the suspect there is no way to do this by just using the phone, perhaps I will need to connect it to a PC and do something via `adb` ?

My phone data:
Model: Huawei ALE-21 (P8 lite)
Android version: 5.0.1

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and back on?  Its the obvious question, I know, but solves a lot problems.

Comment: Thank you @SiXandSeven8ths , unfortunately I tried several times with no success.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how much control you have over your device, but I may have a few ideas.

## 1 requires root and the ability to flash zip files.

Deleting the google apps using an app (this does require root) and then flashing the correct gapps package from www.opengapps.org should reinstall all Google apps, thus remove the data stored in the apps.

## 2 does not require root and should work on a stock device

I believe Huawei phones have the ability to run in safe mode, and not start any apps in the process. This way you should be able to wipe the apps.

Enabling safe mode:
Off.
Press and hold to On.
When "Huawei "logo is displayed, release the key On.
Immediately after releasing the Power key, hold the key Volume down .
Keep holding down the Volume Down key until the phone finishes rebooting.
Release the key Volume down when you see Safe Mode appear in the lower left corner of the screen.
- source: www.howtosafemode.com

Disabling safe mode:
Simply restart :)

I'm currently on my phone so I'm sorry for the bad formatting.

Ideas?
Probably something went wrong with Google Play Services. Just reverting it to stock should fix it.

Comment: Could you explain in more details how to do the two approaches above? I am particularly interested in the second. Also, do you know any approach based on ADB? and what about just clearing the Google Play Services data (still via ADB for example)? You think it would not work?

Comment: It should be possible using adb, however I am not that familiar with adb. I will now add more information on the second method.